# array[key] returns undefined, even though array[0] is defined, and key defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my nav item directive (the last one):

```
pantherDirectives.directive('bootstrapNavBar', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/bootstrapNavBar/wrapper.html',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }
}).directive('navBarHeader', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/bootstrapNavBar/header.html',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }   
}).directive('navBarBody', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/bootstrapNavBar/body.html',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            this.items = [];
        }
    }   
}).directive('navBarDropDown', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }   
}).directive('navItem', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        require: '^navBarBody',
        template: '<li ngclass="" ng-click="" ng-class="thisItem"><a data-ng-transclude></a></li>',
        replace: true,
        priority: 1000,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, navBarBody) {
            var itemNum  = navBarBody.items.push(false);
            var thisItem = navBarBody.items[itemNum];

            console.log(itemNum);               //returns 1 then 2
            console.log(thisItem);             // returns undefined
            console.log(navBarBody.items[0]); //  returns false (as intended)
        }
    }
});
```

my key variable `itemNum` returns something, as does my array when I specify a number as the key, but when the key is my variable I get an `undefined`.

Comment: You're accessing the second element of `navBarBody.items` in `thisItem ` and the first element in `navBarBody.items[0]` maybe your arrays has  a first element but not a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array. Thus, when you push an element into an empty array, you will be returned `1`, but the element will be accessible at `array[0]` (0-indexed), and not `array[1]` which is how you are trying to access it.

```
var arr = [];             // length is 0
var len = arr.push(false);// returns 1 because array's new length is 1
console.log(arr[0]);      // this works because what you pushed is at index 0
console.log(arr[len]);    // won't work because you are essentially doing arr[1]
                          // i.e trying to access the second element (which doesn't exist)
```

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense, is it best to use something other than the array length, or should I just get the length-1? Thanks

Comment: If you just want to access the last element, `length-1` is fine. You can also use [`array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), but that will also remove it from the array.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark), if your question is resolved.

Comment: Sorry didn't accept it before because of the time limit :)